# How to update a model with more conditions than an ID in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, laravel, eloquent

I'm new in Laravel 5.0 and I trying to find a `user` to update him but with some conditions like a status or a expiration date. When I use the `find` method just given the user id is OK to update cause i get an App\User instance thus is possible to update: `$User->fill($newData)->save();`

But when I need to set some conditions to query, the instance is from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and obviously not have a fill method cause isn't a App\User (isn't  an Eloquent model):

```
$User = \Reverse\Interest::find($id)
    ->where('status', '<>', 'DELETED')
    ->where('expires_at', '>=', DB::raw('NOW()'))
```

So, `$User->fill($newData)->save()` is impossible...

How to find a user with ID and more conditions and get a App\User instance to update instead Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `first()` and use `where('id', ...`:

```
$User = \Reverse\Interest::where('id', $id)
    ->where('status', '<>', 'DELETED')
    ->where('expires_at', '>=', DB::raw('NOW()'))
    ->first();

if($User !== null){
    $User->fill($newData)->save();
}
```